# What is the length of an Exponential map?

Tags: group-theory, exponential-function, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

The exponential map for the unit circle is $it \to \exp (it) = \cos t + i \sin t$

This group can be augmented with a norm on the complex plane such that $r$ is the length of the complex number on the plane: $r\exp(it)$. Specifically, where $(a,b)$ is a position on the complex plane, the length is given by $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

This seems like it should be true for any Lie algebra; one can always multiply the element by a scalar and attribute a certain length to it.

For instance , the special linear group has a map $Xt \to \exp (Xt)$. If I assign a length to the special linear group, I also get a length $\exp(a+Xt)=r\exp(Xt)$, which should now be the general linear group.

But, whereas in the case of the complex number the norm was $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, I am at a total loss as to what the expression of the length would be for other algebras. Is the choice arbitrary, or should I take the length of, say the su(2) Lie algebra, to be $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ under the mapping

$$
\ln r+x\sigma_1+y\sigma_2+z\sigma_3\to r\exp(x\sigma_1+y\sigma_2+z\sigma_3)
$$

Now, I have randomly guessed $r$ to be $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, but how do I know its the right formulation. Are there rules to follow?

Is the a special type of plane for each Lie algebra, analogous to the complex plane for the complex numbers, where I can place its element, such that a certain norm is better than the others?

Comment: There are many Riemannian metrics on Lie groups. One usually assumes that the metric is left-invariant; even then you get some freedom. For compact simple Lie groups there is unique biinvariant metric, but uniqueness is only up to scaling. Killing form provides a canonical choice.

Comment: I do not at all understand what this question is asking for.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Well the modulus of a complex number is $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and the complex numbers are a lie group. So what is the modulus for an arbitrary Lie group?

Comment: Well I guess for any given interesting Lie group $G$, you and I could come up with several functions $G \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and we might even be able to make them continuous and have non-negative outputs; and so far, nothing stops us from calling any of them a "modulus" for that specific $G$. My remark is: Unless you become far more specific in what properties such a "modulus for an arbitrary Lie group" is supposed to have, this is not an answerable question.

Comment: Note however that if such a map is supposed to be a non-trivial homomorphism, its kernel is a proper normal subgroup with (sort of) codimension $1$, and thus such a thing would not easily exist on (semi)simple Lie groups. For many other matrix Lie groups, the *determinant* (maybe composed with an absolute value) could be seen as playing the role of such a "modulus". But again, this is just based on guessing what it could be you're looking for.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Would I take the square root of the determinant (complex modulus has the root) or just the determinant directly?  If the matrix representation of the Lie algebra is, say $4 \times 4$, do I take the fourth square root $\sqrt[4]{det g}$?

Comment: Only you can tell -- each has its pros and cons. With a root, it's compatible with real scaling, and generalizes the complex abs. value. But: Roots are either not necessarily defined (like for neg. real numbers) or ambiguous (there are $n$ different $n$-th roots in $\mathbb C$). They also feel wrong from an algebraic viewpoint. But, as said multiple times, you have not clearly stated what you want, so how could one decide? (In any case, note that even the determinant map might depend on a specific matrix representation and be different for different representations of the same group).